# GLAccount Information - Simulate BAPI_INCOMINGINVOICE_CREATE

Tags: invoice, sap-erp, saprfc, bapi, jco

I am currently working on an application that posts invoices to SAP ERP using Java/JCo. I am using `BAPI_INCOMINGINVOICE_CREATE` for the purpose and it works perfectly fine. Now I have an additional requirement to preview the GL Account distribution of the gross amount (credits and debits) before confirming the transaction through `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT`. Essentially it is the same as "Simulate" option provided in `MIRO` transaction.

Is there a way to retrieve `GLACCOUNTDATA` information that the BAPI will populate as a result of the invoice post before actually committing the transaction? The `BAPI_INCOMINGINVOICE_CREATE` call does not seem to return this table by default!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

would it be an option for you to create a salesorder first and then create an invoice from the sales order number?